# thorn bush with yellow fuit/seed in central florida. could this be Ximenia americana?

Tags: identification

What is this thorn bush that produces seeds in late spring early fall.  This picture was taken in april 25, but the seeds grow much bigger and rounder - i suspect need another month.

I found this in Lake Placid Florida in very sandy soil.  Branches are very prickly and stiff. grows outward.

Seems like great security bush and i want to propagate. tried cuttings with no luck, would like to try planting seeds .

could this be Ximenia americana?

[image]

[image]

This was taken Sept 15th... tried to plant cuttings but did not work. planted seed but seems did not germinate.

[image]

[image]